# Loading a JPEG image in Lollipop (5.1.1)

Tags: java, android, bitmap, jpeg

I would like to load a JPEG image as a Bitmap object on an Android App. I am using Android 5.1.1 API 22. I am currently using the following code to load the bitmap, where jpg is the file of the image that I have previously taken:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(jpg.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
```

And I am attempting to perform image processing on the Bitmap extracted above:

```
int width = bMap.getWidth();
int height = bMap.getHeight();
```

I have the following permissions set in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

In the logcat I get the following output:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21173)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6838)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21173) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6838) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

So essentially it's saying that the Bitmap is null (last line in the logcat).

Has anyone else had this problem on android 5.1.1; API 22? Or does anybody have a different way of doing this? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the view not with the bitmap. Can you show us the part where you are calling this code?

Comment: It's not a problem with the view. The view raises an error, because the underlaying bitmap is null and therefore it can not be drawn.
@Justin MacPherson: Are you sure the path to the jpeg file is correct? You could check this using a File object and then check with the .exists() method.

Comment: `android:maxSdkVersion="18"` – Assuming you're using `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for its implicit `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, you still need that permission on SDK versions > 18. Remove that `maxSdkVersion` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are selecting bitmap image from gallery, It is possible that the path you are getting is not proper. 
Add a new XML file called file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <external-path name="my_images"
    path="." />
</paths>
```

add this inside  tag in AndroidManifest

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
```

And this in Activity:

```
public String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            String res = "";
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                res = cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
            cursor.close();
            return res;
        } else {
            String res = "";
            String wholeID = null;
            wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(contentUri);
            String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

            String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().
                    query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                res = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            }
            cursor.close();
            return res;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```